# javascript single naV page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

hi guys ı have a few questions ı am working on single page website(for practicing). ı still didn't complete web site but ı have few problems.

- there is a nav on left side of page. when you are on a certain section of page, nav on left side glow according to that section.
- But FİRST problem is that sides should glow not working properly.

  - it's working kind of but have some bugs like when you scroll the page fast more than a few glow appear
  - (only one glow should appear in a moment).
- SECOND problem is some time I don't see section and there is no glowing part on nav.

  - ı have tried to lengthen those section it made problem appear less but didn't solve it.
- THİRD problem is efficiency of code, ı tried a few things but none of them worked so ı had to use too many 'if' and 'if else'.

  - it's looks so ugly

here is the code:

```js
const allSection = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
const allList = document.querySelectorAll(".list");
const list_1 = document.querySelector(".list-1");
const list_2 = document.querySelector(".list-2");
const list_3 = document.querySelector(".list-3");
const list_4 = document.querySelector(".list-4");
const list_5 = document.querySelector(".list-5");
const list_6 = document.querySelector(".list-6");
const list_7 = document.querySelector(".list-7");
const list_8 = document.querySelector(".list-8");

const markList = function (entries, observer) {
  const [entry] = entries;
  console.log(entry);

  allSection.forEach(function (sect, i) {
    allList.forEach(function (list, index) {
      sect.classList.remove("mark");
      if (
        entry.isIntersecting &&
        entry.target.classList.contains(`section-1`)
      ) {
        list_1.classList.add("mark");
      }
      if (
        !entry.isIntersecting &&
        !entry.target.classList.contains(`section-1`)
      ) {
        list_1.classList.remove("mark");
      }
      if (
        entry.isIntersecting &&
        entry.target.classList.contains(`section-2`)
      ) {
        list_2.classList.add("mark");
      }
      if (
        !entry.isIntersecting &&
        !entry.target.classList.contains(`section-2`)
      ) {
        list_2.classList.remove("mark");
      }
      if (
        entry.isIntersecting &&
        entry.target.classList.contains(`section-3`)
      ) {
        list_3.classList.add("mark");
      }
      if (
        !entry.isIntersecting &&
        !entry.target.classList.contains(`section-3`)
      ) {
        list_3.classList.remove("mark");
      }
      if (
        entry.isIntersecting &&
        entry.target.classList.contains(`section-4`)
      ) {
        list_4.classList.add("mark");
      }
      if (
        !entry.isIntersecting &&
        !entry.target.classList.contains(`section-4`)
      ) {
        list_4.classList.remove("mark");
      }
      if (
        entry.isIntersecting &&
        entry.target.classList.contains(`section-5`)
      ) {
        list_5.classList.add("mark");
      }
      if (
        !entry.isIntersecting &&
        !entry.target.classList.contains(`section-5`)
      ) {
        list_5.classList.remove("mark");
      }
      if (
        entry.isIntersecting &&
        entry.target.classList.contains(`section-6`)
      ) {
        list_6.classList.add("mark");
      }
      if (
        !entry.isIntersecting &&
        !entry.target.classList.contains(`section-6`)
      ) {
        list_6.classList.remove("mark");
      }if (
        entry.isIntersecting &&
        entry.target.classList.contains(`section-7`)
      ) {
        list_7.classList.add("mark");
      }
      if (
        !entry.isIntersecting &&
        !entry.target.classList.contains(`section-7`)
      ) {
        list_7.classList.remove("mark");
      }
      if (
        entry.isIntersecting &&
        entry.target.classList.contains(`section-8`)
      ) {
        list_8.classList.add("mark");
      }
      if (
        !entry.isIntersecting &&
        !entry.target.classList.contains(`section-8`)
      ) {
        list_8.classList.remove("mark");
      }
    });
  });
};

//
//    if(entry.isIntersecting && entry.target.classList.contains(`section-${it}`)){
//
//        allList.forEach(l=>l.classList.remove('mark'))
//        allList[it].classList.add('mark')
//    }
//    else return;
//}
const sectObserver = new IntersectionObserver(markList, {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0.4,
});

allSection.forEach((sect) => sectObserver.observe(sect));
```

```css
* {
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.01fr 10fr 10fr 10fr 10fr 10fr 10fr 10fr 10fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main";
}
.content{
  height: 300px;
}
.content-1 {
  grid-area: content-1;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.content-2 {
  grid-area: content-2;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.content-3 {
  grid-area: content-3;
  background-color: palevioletred;
}
.content-4 {
  grid-area: content-4;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
.content-5 {
  grid-area: content-5;
  background-color:peachpuff
}
.content-6 {
  grid-area: content-6;
  background-color:peru
}
.content-7 {
  grid-area: content-7;
  background-color:plum
}
.content-8 {
  grid-area: content-8;
  background-color:powderblue
}
.content-9 {
  grid-area: content-9;
  background-color:purple
}
.main {
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 5rem;
  margin-left: 4.85rem;
  background-color: white;
  grid-area: main;
}
.sidebar {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #015360;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.logo {
  background-color: #015360;
}
.Name {
  grid-area: logo;
  margin-top: 20.5%;
  margin-left: 8.8%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.Uplist {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 1.9rem;
  display: block;
}
.list {
  color: white;
  padding: 0.6rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
}
.barber {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3rem;
  margin-top: 1.88rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.color ul {
  list-style: square;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 1.15rem;
  margin: 0;
}
.color {
  color: #777;
}
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.title {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  color: black;
}
.wel-come {
  margin-top: 2.1rem;
}
.features {
  margin-top: 40px;
  line-height: 33px;
}
.features h2 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.second {
  margin-top: 23px;
}
.instal {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.instal ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
}
.tmpl-structure{
  width: 100%;
  height: 430px;
}
.mark{
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="start.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <main class="main">
    <section class="Welcome section section-1">
      <div class="barber">
        <h1>Barber</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="wel-come">
        <h2 class="title">Welcome To Barber</h2>
        <div class="color">
          <p>
            Firstly, a huge thanks for purchasing this theme, your support
            is truly appreciated!
          </p>
          <p>
            This document covers the installation and use of this theme and
            often reveals answers to common problems and issues - read this
            documentthoroughly if you are experiencing any difficulties. If
            you have any questions that are beyond the scope of this
            document. Thank you so much!
          </p>

          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="features">
        <h2 class="title">Template Features</h2>
        <div class="color">
          <ul>
            <li>Clean & Simple Design</li>
            <li>HTML5 & CSS3</li>
            <li>Fully Responsive Design</li>
            <li>PHP/Ajax Powered Working Contact Form</li>
            <li>All files are well commented</li>
            <li>
              Cross Browser Compatible with IE11+, Firefox, Safari, Opera,
              Chrome
            </li>
            <li>Extensive Documentation</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="Installing section section-2" style="height:1500px;">
      <div class="barber second">
        <h1>Barber</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="color instal">
        <h2 class="title">Installing Template</h2>
        <ol>
          <li>
            After unzip the download pack, you'll found a Template Folder
            with all the files.
          </li>
          <li>
            You can view this Template in any browser, you can display or
            edit the Template without an internet connection.(May not wotrk
            fonts and google map)
          </li>
          <li>
            The only section that will not work is the Contact Section which
            contains PHP code and requires a server environment for send
            messages.
          </li>
          <li>
            Now go to your cpanel or open your FTP Client (like Filezilla)
            and upload the content of the Template on your server root.
          </li>
          <li>
            Once the files are done uploading go to
            www.yourdomainname.com/index.html
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="tmpl-structure section section-3">
      <h2 class="title">Template Structure</h2>
      <p class="fifteen">
        All information within the main content area is nested within a body
        tag. The general template structure is pretty the same throughout
        the template. Here is the general structure of main page
        (index.html).
      </p>
      <div class="bos"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="css-structure section section-4" style="height: 600px">
      <h2 class="title">CSS Files and Structure</h2>
      <p class="fifteen">
        These are the css files that are loaded into templates in
        <strong>Head Section</strong>.
      </p>
      <h2 class="title">Google Web Fonts</h2>
      <p>
        By default, the template loads this font from Google Web Font
        Services, you can change the font with the one that suits you best.
      </p>
      <p class="twenty">
        Remember to change the font into <strong>style.css</strong>
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="javascript section section-5" style="height: 600px">
      <h2 class="title">Javascript Files and Structure</h2>
      <p class="fifteen">
        These are the list of Javascript files that are loaded into
        templates in end of the <strong>Body Section</strong>.
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="contact-form section section-6" style="height: 600px">
      <h2 class="title">Contact Form</h2>
      <p>
        This is a PHP Script for sending messages to your email, you should
        replace <strong>demo@site.com</strong> to your email to start
        receive messages.
      </p>
      <pre class="brush:php">
              $to = 'demo@site.com'; // replace this mail with yours
              $firstname = $_POST["fname"];
              $email= $_POST["email"];
              $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
              $headers .= "From: " . $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
              $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
      
              $message ='<table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                  <td>'.$firstname.'  '.$laststname.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Email: '.$email.'</td></tr>
              </table>';
      
              if (@mail($to, $email, $message, $headers))
              {
                echo 'The message has been sent.';
              }else{
              echo 'failed';
            }
          </pre>
    </section>
    <section class="subscription-form section section-7" style="height: 600px">
      <h2 class="title">Subscription Form</h2>
      <p>
        Replace this action with your own mailchimp post URL. Don't remove
        the "". Just paste the url inside "".
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="video section-8" style="height: 600px">
      <h2 class="title">Video Tutorial</h2>
    </section>
  </main> 
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h1 class="Name">BARBER</h1>
      <ul class="Uplist">
        <li class="list list-1">Welcome</li>
        <li class="list list-2">Installation</li>
        <li class="list list-3">Structure</li>
        <li class="list list-4">CSS Files</li>
        <li class="list list-5">Javascript Libraries</li>
        <li class="list list-6">Contact Form</li>
        <li class="list list-7">Subscription form</li>
        <li class="list list-8">Video Tutorial</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
 

  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<script defer src="start.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this closer to what you want https://jsfiddle.net/uawrtvpL/

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.section');

function handleIntersection(entries) {
  entries.map((entry, i) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      let index = entry.target.elems_index;
      document.querySelectorAll(".list").forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.remove("mark")
      })
      document.querySelector(".list-" + index.toString()).classList.add("mark");
    }
  });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);

images.forEach((elem, index) => {
  // save index as element’s property before register the element in observer
  elem.elems_index = index + 1;
  observer.observe(elem);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.01fr 10fr 10fr 10fr 10fr 10fr 10fr 10fr 10fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main"
    "sidebar main main main main main";
}
.content{
  height: 300px;
}
.content-1 {
  grid-area: content-1;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.content-2 {
  grid-area: content-2;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.content-3 {
  grid-area: content-3;
  background-color: palevioletred;
}
.content-4 {
  grid-area: content-4;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
.content-5 {
  grid-area: content-5;
  background-color:peachpuff
}
.content-6 {
  grid-area: content-6;
  background-color:peru
}
.content-7 {
  grid-area: content-7;
  background-color:plum
}
.content-8 {
  grid-area: content-8;
  background-color:powderblue
}
.content-9 {
  grid-area: content-9;
  background-color:purple
}
.main {
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 5rem;
  margin-left: 4.85rem;
  background-color: white;
  grid-area: main;
}
.sidebar {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #015360;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.logo {
  background-color: #015360;
}
.Name {
  grid-area: logo;
  margin-top: 20.5%;
  margin-left: 8.8%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.Uplist {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 1.9rem;
  display: block;
}
.list {
  color: white;
  padding: 0.6rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
}
.barber {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3rem;
  margin-top: 1.88rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.color ul {
  list-style: square;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 1.15rem;
  margin: 0;
}
.color {
  color: #777;
}
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.title {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  color: black;
}
.wel-come {
  margin-top: 2.1rem;
}
.features {
  margin-top: 40px;
  line-height: 33px;
}
.features h2 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.second {
  margin-top: 23px;
}
.instal {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.instal ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
}
.tmpl-structure{
  width: 100%;
  height: 430px;
}
.mark{
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="start.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <main class="main">
        <section class="Welcome section section-1">
          <div class="barber">
            <h1>Barber</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="wel-come">
            <h2 class="title">Welcome To Barber</h2>
            <div class="color">
              <p>
                Firstly, a huge thanks for purchasing this theme, your support
                is truly appreciated!
              </p>
              <p>
                This document covers the installation and use of this theme and
                often reveals answers to common problems and issues - read this
                documentthoroughly if you are experiencing any difficulties. If
                you have any questions that are beyond the scope of this
                document. Thank you so much!
              </p>

              <p></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="features">
            <h2 class="title">Template Features</h2>
            <div class="color">
              <ul>
                <li>Clean & Simple Design</li>
                <li>HTML5 & CSS3</li>
                <li>Fully Responsive Design</li>
                <li>PHP/Ajax Powered Working Contact Form</li>
                <li>All files are well commented</li>
                <li>
                  Cross Browser Compatible with IE11+, Firefox, Safari, Opera,
                  Chrome
                </li>
                <li>Extensive Documentation</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section class="Installing section section-2" style="height:1500px;">
          <div class="barber second">
            <h1>Barber</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="color instal">
            <h2 class="title">Installing Template</h2>
            <ol>
              <li>
                After unzip the download pack, you'll found a Template Folder
                with all the files.
              </li>
              <li>
                You can view this Template in any browser, you can display or
                edit the Template without an internet connection.(May not wotrk
                fonts and google map)
              </li>
              <li>
                The only section that will not work is the Contact Section which
                contains PHP code and requires a server environment for send
                messages.
              </li>
              <li>
                Now go to your cpanel or open your FTP Client (like Filezilla)
                and upload the content of the Template on your server root.
              </li>
              <li>
                Once the files are done uploading go to
                www.yourdomainname.com/index.html
              </li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section class="tmpl-structure section section-3">
          <h2 class="title">Template Structure</h2>
          <p class="fifteen">
            All information within the main content area is nested within a body
            tag. The general template structure is pretty the same throughout
            the template. Here is the general structure of main page
            (index.html).
          </p>
          <div class="bos"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="css-structure section section-4" style="height: 600px">
          <h2 class="title">CSS Files and Structure</h2>
          <p class="fifteen">
            These are the css files that are loaded into templates in
            <strong>Head Section</strong>.
          </p>
          <h2 class="title">Google Web Fonts</h2>
          <p>
            By default, the template loads this font from Google Web Font
            Services, you can change the font with the one that suits you best.
          </p>
          <p class="twenty">
            Remember to change the font into <strong>style.css</strong>
          </p>
        </section>
        <section class="javascript section section-5" style="height: 600px">
          <h2 class="title">Javascript Files and Structure</h2>
          <p class="fifteen">
            These are the list of Javascript files that are loaded into
            templates in end of the <strong>Body Section</strong>.
          </p>
        </section>
        <section class="contact-form section section-6" style="height: 900px">
          <h2 class="title">Contact Form</h2>
          <p>
            This is a PHP Script for sending messages to your email, you should
            replace <strong>demo@site.com</strong> to your email to start
            receive messages.
          </p>
          <pre class="brush:php">
              $to = 'demo@site.com'; // replace this mail with yours
              $firstname = $_POST["fname"];
              $email= $_POST["email"];
              $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
              $headers .= "From: " . $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
              $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
      
              $message ='<table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                  <td>'.$firstname.'  '.$laststname.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Email: '.$email.'</td></tr>
              </table>';
      
              if (@mail($to, $email, $message, $headers))
              {
                echo 'The message has been sent.';
              }else{
              echo 'failed';
            }
          </pre>
        </section>
        <section class="subscription-form section section-7" style="height: 600px">
          <h2 class="title">Subscription Form</h2>
          <p>
            Replace this action with your own mailchimp post URL. Don't remove
            the "". Just paste the url inside "".
          </p>
        </section>
        <section class="video section section-8" style="height: 600px">
          <h2 class="title">Video Tutorial</h2>
        </section>
      </main>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h1 class="Name">BARBER</h1>
        <ul class="Uplist">
          <li class="list list-1">Welcome</li>
          <li class="list list-2">Installation</li>
          <li class="list list-3">Structure</li>
          <li class="list list-4">CSS Files</li>
          <li class="list list-5">Javascript Libraries</li>
          <li class="list list-6">Contact Form</li>
          <li class="list list-7">Subscription form</li>
          <li class="list list-8">Video Tutorial</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<script defer src="start.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it's closer to what i want thank you. In this code when scrolling up , two section passing without glowing. I will try to fix that when i go home. And thank you again, have a good day

Comment: check out the jsfiddle link, it seems to work perfectly there, I think it doesn't here because StackOverflow uses an iframe to display and run code examples which might be throwing the code off

Comment: sorry there is a part ı didnt understand. what is "elems_index". ı see that you get it from  entry.target , ı'd take a look intersection observer but didnt see something like that also you have used it in bottom part of code  (elem.elems_index = index + 1;). Can you please explain this to me. Also you didnt use any threshold, is there any default threshold ?

Comment: elems_index is a made-up thing, it holds the id of the element index which we can use later on as a reference so we know which element we need to add the list-X class to. As the index starts at 0 but the list-X starts as 1 we add +1 to the index to they match up. I didn't add a threshold as it seemed to work better without one, I think the scroll up is buggy because the last few (section-8 in particular) are so narrow in height that the observer doesn't like it. Playing around with the html/css yields different behavior. You might be better off using Scroll listener over Intersection Observers